# How to extend lan to offsite location

Tags: local-area-network, connection, site-to-site-vpn

I would like to extend my LAN to another site.
I have people who work on both sites and I want it to be as if they are in the same LAN, regardless of where they are.

I have servers on both sites and they should not be aware that they are separated by the internet.

So What I want is to have a "virtual network cable" that connects my 2 sites.

Any suggestions?

Please keep in mind that it has to be as if I have a real network cable connecting the switch of site 1 with the switch of site 2!

Thanks in advance!

Johan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literally a "virtual network cable" would be a VPN in `TAP` mode, simulating *link layer* (L2), both end having the same subnet. However, things will work as required even if you have different subnets on every site i.e. use VPN in `TUN`neled mode, simulating *network layer* (L3). Actually the `TUN` mode has advantages: for example Windows domain is site-aware and can refer to the nearest domain controller, causing less network traffic between the sites.

If you don't want to setup everything from scratch, which is not a good idea if you don't have much knowledge on VPN technology, you may want to have routers/firewalls that have easy out-of-box wizard based site-to-site VPN setup.

Comment: We have Sophos UTM9 on both sides, but all I can find is examples with 2 different ip subnets. I would like to have just one, so all servers and clients are in the same address range etc. Is that possible with our setup?

Comment: With Sophos UTM9 it's by design that you should have different subnets. However, that shouldn't be a problem in your use case. It's completely normal to have routing between the sites and they are still in the same private network.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We went with 2 different ip subnets, changed the IP's of the servers and it all works great. I expected problems after changing the IP addresses but there weren't any.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't specify the operating system or others needs I would confirm that you need a VPN. You could check out the [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html) software.

> OpenVPN is a full-featured SSL VPN which implements OSI layer 2 or 3 secure network extension using the industry standard SSL/TLS protocol, supports flexible client authentication methods based on certificates, smart cards, and/or username/password credentials, and allows user or group-specific access control policies using firewall rules applied to the VPN virtual interface. OpenVPN is not a web application proxy and does not operate through a web browser.